# Curl response in php

Tags: php, curl

Am using Curl to send sms using a gateway , a, getting 200 when everything is ok and 400 if its not send now , i should get other things from the gateway such as phone number and other information , so am i missing something ?

```
// if the Form is submited 
//if (isset($_POST['PhoneNumber'])) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

// Fetch Phone Number and escape it for security 
$Phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PhoneNumber']);

// Fetch Text and escape it for security 
$Text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Text']);

// Structure the URl
$url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx:xxxx?PhoneNumber=".urlencode($Phone)."&Text=".urlencode($Text)."&User=xxx&Password=xxx";

// Handeling the Curl
$handle = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($httpCode=="200"){

  // if everything is okey , the gateway returns 200 which means OK
  echo "Massage Was Sent , Thank you ";



} elseif ($httpCode=="400"){
  // if there was an error , the form returns a 400 which means that the sms Failed 
  echo "Massage was not sent , Please Try Again";

}

// Cloase the Curl Connection
curl_close($handle);
```

Thank you Best regards,

Comment: i'm not familiar with curl at all, but `curl_getinfo` are you sure you don't want the `$response` variable?  you are specifying the `$handle`. because i'd think that you would want to be getting the info on the response.  could be wrong though.

Comment: i dont understand , what should i do ?

Comment: Thanks for the massage :) (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

$response should contain the response, try:
`echo '<pre>';
  print_r($response);
      echo '</pre>';`
to show its content